# Page numbering fontsize without fancyhdr

Tags: fontsize, page-numbering

I want to make the fontsize of the page numbers 10 pt. But I want to make it without fancyhdr. Because when I use fancyhdr, it draws a line on the header part which my university does not want. Can I do something in the redefinition of "plain" and "myheadings" page styles? 
Also another question is can I make the frontmatter of a document until the  mainmatter single sided? With that I want to make the page numbers standing always on the upper right  part. Here is the code I used:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[turkish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.75cm,right=2.75cm,top=2.8cm,bottom=2.9cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.6cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.7cm}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thechapter}{15pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{12pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{12pt}{}

%Ana bölüm başlıklarındaki boşluğu ayarlama
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-1.295cm}{18pt} 


\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\addto\captionsturkish{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Çizelge} }

\addto\captionsturkish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{\centerline{KAYNAKLAR}}}



\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}

\onehalfspacing

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{18pt}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{times}

%kelime ayırmayı engelleme
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

%sayfa numaralandırma
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\pagenumbering{roman}

%Ana bölüm başlangıcındaki sayfalarda sayfa numarasını yukarıda çıkarmak için
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{myheadings}

%TOC, LOT ve LOF ilk sayfalarının numaralarını değiştirme
%İlk sayfalar "plain" tipinde olduğu için burada yeniden tanımlanıyor.
\makeatletter
    \def\ps@plain{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty%
    \let\@evenfoot\@empty%
    \def\@oddhead{\reset@font\hfil\thepage}%
    \def\@evenhead{\reset@font\thepage\hfil}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength\cfttabindent{0pt} %tablo listesini sola hizalama
\setlength\cftfigindent{0pt} %şekil listesini sola hizalama
%İçindekilerdeki koyu olanları normale çevirme
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\mdseries}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\mdseries}
%chapter başlığını göstermeme
\newcommand\invisiblechapterx[1]{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Sayfa}\par} %İçindekilerin başında "sayfa" yazma
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
    \chaptermark{#1}}
\newcommand\invisiblechapter[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
    \chaptermark{#1}}

%tablo içindeki yazıları sola hizalama
\usepackage{chngpage}

%Kaynaklar kısmındaki numaralandırmanın köşeli parantezlerini kaldırma
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother
%Math modunda normal yazmak için
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{bm}
%İçindekilerdeki ana bölümlere nokta ekleme
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters

%İçindekiler ve diğer listelere "Sayfa" yazısı eklemek için
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{turkish}
\setcounter{page}{4}

%Özet - Sayfa numaraları buradan itibaren görünecek
\invisiblechapterx{ÖZET}
\begin{center}
    \blindtext\\
(Yüksek Lisans Tezi)\\
\noindent

Fatih GÜLEÇ\\

\noindent


ÖZET
\end{center}
\singlespacing
\noindent \blindtext

\onehalfspacing


\newpage

%Abstract
\invisiblechapter{ABSTRACT}
\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{center}
    \blindtext

    ABSTRACT
\end{center}
\singlespacing
\noindent \blindtext

\onehalfspacing

\selectlanguage{turkish}
\newpage

%Teşekkür
\invisiblechapter{TEŞEKKÜR}
\begin{center}
    \textbf{TEŞEKKÜR}
\end{center}

\noindent \blindtext

\newpage

\renewcommand\contentsname{\hfill\bfseries\normalsize İÇİNDEKİLER \hfill}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{\hfill\bfseries\normalsize ŞEKİLLERİN LİSTESİ \hfill}
\renewcommand\listtablename{\hfill\bfseries\normalsize ÇİZELGELERİN LİSTESİ \hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

%İçindekiler başlığındaki boşluğu ayarlama
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-18pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{İÇİNDEKİLER} %İçindekiler satırı
\tableofcontents %İçindekiler


\addtocontents{lof}{\textbf{Şekil}~\hfill\textbf{Sayfa}\par}
\addtocontents{lot}{\textbf{Çizelge}~\hfill\textbf{Sayfa}\par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{~\hfill\textbf{Sayfa}\par\medskip}}                  %İçindekiler ve diğer listelere "Sayfa" yazısı ekleme


\newpage

\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{-18pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ÇİZELGELERİN LİSTESİ}
\listoftables %Çizelge Listesi

\newpage

\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-18pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ŞEKİLLERİN LİSTESİ}
\listoffigures %Şekil Listesi


%Simgeler ve Kısaltmalar
\newpage
\invisiblechapter{SİMGELER VE KISALTMALAR}
\begin{center}
    \textbf{SİMGELER VE KISALTMALAR}
\end{center}
\noindent Bu çalışmada kullanılmış simgeler ve kısaltmalar, açıklamaları ile birlikte     aşağıda sunulmuştur.

\noindent



\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can remove the rule drawn by `fancyhdr` by adding `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` after `\pagestyle{fancy}`.

Comment: Ot you can use `titleps` instead of fancyhdr.

Comment: Hint: Your second question will be seen by more people if put in a question of its own.

Comment: You can also create headers using everypage, \raisebox and \rlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with fancyhdr, unfortunately. Instead of redefinition of  plain or existing pages in the documentclass, I defined 3 types of page styles for frontmatter, mainmatter and plain(chapter,TOC, LOF, LOT starting pages) pages. The pages are without a horizontal line on the header and 10 pt page numbers. You can find the code below:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[R]{\normalfont\fontsize{10pt}{11pt}\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}} % except the center

\fancypagestyle{main}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\normalfont\fontsize{10pt}{11pt}\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\fancypagestyle{mainfront}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[R]{\normalfont\fontsize{10pt}{11pt}\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\pagenumbering{roman}
```

Comment: Please note, that this will print in fact the page numbers on the right hand side of the pages, but the document will not be one-sided.

Comment: @Johannes_B How can I do then the part before the main document one-sided?

Comment: Please open a new question for that. It is a completely different matter and should be treated that way.